# How to get key value pair from TableResult in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I have a TableResult, I want to iterate it and put key and it's value in a Hashmap. I am able to do this but I am not sure if this is right way to achieve.

I have tried with following:

```
HashMap<String, String> rowData = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field s : result.getSchema().getFields()) {
    keys.add(s.getName());
}
for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
    for (String column : keys) {
        if (row.get(column).getValue() == null)
            rowData.put(column, (String) row.get(column).getValue());
        else
            rowData.put(column, row.get(column).getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

Here I am iterating TableResult two times first to get keys and second is to get key's value. Please suugest the right way.

Comment: Does it work? If so, move on and don't worry about it. It looks fine. :)

Comment: @GrahamPolley, Yes it works but again what if I have 1000 elements in a TableResult. It will iterate 2000 times which is not a good way so that is why I am looking for it.

Comment: What is the usecase for a HashMap? Have you looked at BagState which stores data in memory for stateful computations in beam.

Comment: Why do you say it iterates result set twice? First loop is on schema fields, column list not the rows.